# Is it possible to resconstruct the triangle with the following information?

Tags: geometry

Can we construct a triangle given $\angle\theta$, S and L such that L bisects $\angle\theta$?

[image: Sample triangle]

[Source @ 1:41](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=elPt0BfU_bA#t=103)

Comment: What have you managed to show?

Comment: I think something combining [Stewart's Theorem](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Stewart's_Theorem) and the [Angle Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) might do the trick. I'll have to work on it myself to know for sure though.

Comment: Continuing S.B.'s comment if you show us what you have tried others may be able to give you hints or answers that build upon what you know.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [inscribed circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) for $S$ and $\theta$, then use $L$ to determine the point on the circle.